# What is the right word for nationality in Korean?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

In the dictionary, `Korean` is translated to '한국 사람'. But Google translates it like 'Korea Love'?

Do all other nationalities in Korean also end with '사람'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You confused 사람 (with a final consonant of ㅁ) 'person' with 사랑 (with ㅇ) 'love'.

Nationalities in Korean are expressed in the format 'Country name+사람'. Examples:

> - 한국 사람: a Korean
> - 미국 사람: an American
> - 독일 사람: a German

This works also for cities: 서울 사람 for a Seoul citizen, 뉴욕 사람 for a New Yorker, 파리 사람 for a Parisian, etc.

Comment: I see a typo. '마극' should be '미국'

Comment: I changed '미극' to '미국' and some others. Please take a look.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @Taladris' great answer, Korean uses '[-인 (人)](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=30803300)' after a country name to indicate their nationalities. For example:

> 한국인: a Korean
>
> 미국인: an American
>
> 독일인: a German
>
> 그녀는 영국인이다: She is British.

'-인' could also be suffixed to other nouns such as '종교 (religion)' and '문화 (culture)', etc.

'한국인' and '한국 사람' could be used interchangeably, but the former is far more broadly used.

You need to note that '종교 사람' and '문화 사람' can't be used for '종교인 (a religious person)' and '문화인 (a cultured person)' respectively.